# Azure Search not working for other language

Tags: content-search, multilingual, azure-search

Using Sitecore 8.2 update 3.
I'm new to search & Azure Search and followed this approach to implement the site search functionality on our multi-lingual site.

https://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/indexing-subcontent/

There are two issues now:
1. The search works for the English version, but only partially. When I search for a particular keyword "stories", it doesn't return any results. But this word is added to the `content` as I check in debug.  (The thai text is also added to the field.)

2. No results are returned when search in the Thai version.

I have not modified any default Sitecore configs.

Is the patch config correct. Is there a different way to retrieve results for Azure Search. Because the same code `GetSearchResults` works fine when checked with Lucene.

**MyAzureSearch.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>      
      <setting name="ContentSearch.DefaultIndexType">
        <patch:attribute name="value">Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ContentSearch.DefaultIndexConfigurationPath">
        <patch:attribute name="value">contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <!-- indexes subcontent contents into parent's _content field in the index (for better site search) -->
            <field fieldName="_content" cloudFieldName="content__" type="MySite.Feature.Search.Models.SubcontentField, MySite.Feature.Search" boost="1f" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
          </fields>
        </defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Adding content to the computed field:**

```
public class SubcontentField : IComputedIndexField
{
    /// This function is triggered when rebuilding indexes is performed in CMS
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        var sitecoreIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (sitecoreIndexable == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Item homeItem = GetHomeItem(SiteName, MasterDatabaseName);
        List<string> contentToAdd = new List<string>();

        //add values (of only the page items that are under home) to the computed field.
        if (homeItem != null && (sitecoreIndexable.Item.ID == homeItem.ID || sitecoreIndexable.Item.Paths.IsDescendantOf(homeItem)))
        {
            // find renderings with datasources set
            IEnumerable<Item> customDataSources = ExtractRenderingDataSourceItems(sitecoreIndexable.Item);
            IEnumerable<Item> relatedItems = customDataSources.SelectMany(GetRelatedItems);

            // extract text from data sources
            contentToAdd = customDataSources.SelectMany(GetItemContent).ToList();

            contentToAdd.AddRange(relatedItems.SelectMany(GetItemContent));

            if (contentToAdd.Count == 0) return null;
        }

        return string.Join("|", contentToAdd);
    }
}
```

**Get search results:**

```
private void GetSearchResults(string keywords)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
    {
        string index = string.Format("sitecore_{0}_index", Sitecore.Context.Database.Name.ToLower());

        using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(index).CreateSearchContext())
        {
            //baseQuery, set to True, so if we have no searchTerm, all items are returned.
            var baseQuery = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
            var containsQuery = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();

            //here we are breaking up all the terms in the searchTerm                    
            var tokens = keywords.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var token in tokens)
            {
                var currentToken = token;
                containsQuery = containsQuery.Or(item => item.Name.Contains(currentToken));
                containsQuery = containsQuery.Or(item => item.Content.Contains(currentToken));
                containsQuery = containsQuery.Or(item => item.Content.Contains(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(currentToken)));
            }

            //join the baseQuery and the containsQuery
            baseQuery = baseQuery.And(containsQuery);
            IQueryable<SearchResultItem> query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Where(baseQuery)
                .Where(x => x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);                    

            if (query != null && query.Count() > 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would suggest keeping the default field `_content` as is and try

[image]

I haven't tried the multi-lingual search, make sure these [configurations](http://bit.ly/2BMovMs) are added in your Sitecore instance.

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload for the GetQueryable() you can try:

```
var culture = Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo;
var queryable = context.GetQueryable<TYPE>(new CultureExecutionContext(culture));
```

Use this along with the predicate where you specify the language and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Multilingual search is supported starting from 8.2 Update-7, see [Release Notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update7/Release%20Notes)